# Fail to deploy an aplication to JBoss7 while migrating an application from JBoss 6 to JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have migrated an existing application from JBoss 6 to JBoss 7.
After deploying the .ear file i am getting the following error:

```
Caused by:org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:   

JBAS017052: Failed to parse POJO xml [ "/content/SMS-ear.ear/lib/jboss-ejb3-core-
1.1.5.jar /META-INF/ejb3-deployers-jboss-beans.xml" ]
```

After trying out the mention suggestion,I am getting the following error :

```
//New StackTrace after trying out the advice
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information
for class org.domain.sms.session.AuthenticatorAction with ClassLoader 
ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SMS-ear.ear.SMS-ejb.jar:main" from Service 
at class org.domain.sms.session.AuthenticatorAction with ClassLoader 
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex        (DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

Comment: Any special reason not to go to WildFly 8? You get much bugfixed AS7 + EE7 support.

Comment: New stacktrace you posted is not complete enough to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

You should not bundle jboss jars as part of your deployment.

in your case you have jboss-ejb3-core-1.1.5.jar in your ear/lib, 
that jar is implementation of ejb3 on JBoss AS6 and is not meant to be bundled with your deployment.

JBoss AS7 has different implementation behind the scenes.
Failure that you get related to fact that AS7 has different kernel and does not use/define deployers via jboss-beans.xml files anymore.

In short, if you remove that jar(or any other similar as6 jars) from deployment it should work.

Comment: :I tried with the suggestion but still getting an error> i posted it.Any suggestion.Thanks for help.